# GeoExplorer: "Could not create layer record for layer group"

Tags: geoserver, layers, error, geoexplorer

I installed GeoServer via OpenGeo Suite, and still working on it.

I created a "Layer Group" and add layers from local PostGIS. I tried to preview it from "Layer Preview" and show perfectly through the "OpenLayers" option, but unable to show in "GeoExplorer".

I got the javascript warning message says: `"Could not create layer record for layer 'testgroup'. Check if the layer is found in the WMS GetCapabilities response."` on GeoExplorer.js:1441

To view the source code shows like:

```
1441: {name:"fixed",type:"boolean"},{name:"selected",type:"boolean"},{name:"restUrl",type:"string"},{name:"infoFormat",type:"string"},{name:"getFeatureInfo"}];c.fields.each(function(a){i.push(a)});b=new (GeoExt.data.LayerRecord.create(i))(h,b.id);b.json=a}else window.console&&0<this.store.getCount()&&void 0!==a.name&&console.warn("Could not create layer record for layer '"+a.name+"'. Check if the layer is found in the WMS GetCapabilities response.");return b},getProjection:function(a){var b=this.getMapProjection(),
    "Could not create layer record for layer 'testgroup'. Check if the layer is found in the WMS GetCapabilities response."
1442: c=b,a=a.get("srs");if(!a[b.getCode()]){var c=null,d,e;for(e in a)if((d=new OpenLayers.Projection(e)).equals(b)){c=d;break}}return c},initDescribeLayerStore:function(){var a=this.store.reader.raw;this.lazy&&(a={capability:{request:{describelayer:{href:this.url}}},version:this.version||"1.1.1"});var b=a.capability.request.describelayer;if(b)a=a.version,1.1<parseFloat(a)&&(a="1.1.1"),a={SERVICE:"WMS",VERSION:a,REQUEST:"DescribeLayer"},this.describeLayerStore=new GeoExt.data.WMSDescribeLayerStore({url:this.trimUrl(b.href,
```

I am sure that I can preview them separately in GeoExplore from "Layer Preview" page.

It seems everything goes well when I checked it from `http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wms?SERVICE=WMS&REQUEST=GetCapabilities`, without any  error massages or exceptions shown, and the layer group description show at the bottom of the page.

Does anyone run into the same problem?

**//UPDATE**

I found that I missed a javascript error massage when I view the `REQUEST=GetCapabilities` page.

It says: `"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'boxSizing' of null"` on ContentVeil.js:11

To view the source code shows like:

```
11: veil.style.boxSizing = "border-box";
    "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'boxSizing' of null"
12: veil.style.borderStyle = "solid";
```

I am wondering where the error comes from.

Furthermore,

I cannot load the **"field list"** when editting limit condition in style's rules in GeoExplorer.

Comment: I just came across this problem, system was working fine last week, all I did was create styles, and some DB views within the DB software rather than geoserver. Come back to it a week later and only openlayers shows my layers from postGIS. Geoexplorer only shows the Medford stuff from the local aerver not my PostGIS tables

Comment: I have no idea how but it has fixed itself..... I did delete my styles, however they were all validated. Tried a few browsers, I was just about to compare the URL from a Medford layer to my PostGIS layer and it loaded. I have had issues with styles with images before...

Answer (score 1):

I've solved the problem, but still don't know how is everything working.

I discover there is a bug in sometimes that request to `http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wms?`

If without the request parameter `&service=wms`, it will go wrong and response with error message says: `ServiceException code="MissingParameterValue"` in firebug Network page.

The same problem happened when I request to WFS service, if I add `&service=wms` in the end of URL, everything is just going fine.

I guess there should be a default value that I never notice or set up, broken by my unintentional mistake.

**And here is my solutions:**

- Go to the GeoServer "Service" page, choose WMS or WFS service

  ```
  http://localhost:8080/geoserver/web/?wicket:bookmarkablePage=:org.geoserver.wms.web.WMSAdminPage
  ```
- enable the both `Service Metadata` options, especially `Strict CITE compliance`
- `Submit`, then change it back to previous setting.

At this moment, it should get the right response even without the parameter `&service=wms` in URL.

I guess the option`Strict CITE compliance` must overwrite something and recover it at the same time, but I'm not pretty sure about that.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread. But I recently had the pleasure of encountering the same problem! I tried the provided answer but it did not solve my problem.

I was actually just not focusing. When I created the layers from SQl I used the attribute/metadata table instead of the tables that contained the geometry/features.

Using the right data source fixed my problem. Maybe this will help someone else.